# Jquerymobile create button using javascript

Tags: javascript, button, jquery-mobile

i am trying to create href using javascript which should have data-role="button". But the button is not showing. Here is my code.

```
var a = document.createElement("A");
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Skúsiť Znova"));
a.setAttribute("onClick","checkConnection();");
a.setAttribute("data-role","button");
a.setAttribute("data-inline","true");
a.setAttribute("data-corner","false");
```

I append this to div as child and I can see text and also onClick parameter is working great. But for some reason it isnt showing as button but as normaln href. Any suggestions on how to create jquerymobile button dynamicaly with JS? This is whole code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = document.createElement("A");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var p2 = document.createElement("p");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Skúsiť Znova"));
    a.setAttribute("onClick","checkConnection();");
    a.setAttribute("data-role","button");
    a.setAttribute("data-inline","true");
    a.setAttribute("data-corner","false");
    div.setAttribute("id","alertMessage");
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Pripojenie zlyhalo"));
    p2.setAttribute("style","text-align: center;");
    span.setAttribute("class","red");
    p.appendChild(span);
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" (skontrolujte nastavenia siete)."));    
    div.appendChild(p);
    p2.appendChild(a);
    div.appendChild(p2);
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("alert");
    mainDiv.appendChild(div);
    $('mainDiv').trigger('create');
    var toppos=($(window).height()/2) - ($("#alertMessage").height()/2);
    var leftpos=($(window).width()/2) - ($("#alertMessage").width()/2);
    $("#alertMessage").css("top", toppos).css("left",leftpos);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `trigger('create')` to apply all of the jQuery Mobile formatting. Full working code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var a = document.createElement("A");
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Skúsiť Znova"));
a.setAttribute("onClick","checkConnection();");
a.setAttribute("data-role","button");
a.setAttribute("data-inline","true");
a.setAttribute("data-corner","false");

$('#container').append(a).trigger('create');
```

This can be seen in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/sQ2dA/.

---

In response to your edits: the issue is that you have `mainDiv` in quotes, so you are passing a string on this line:

```
$('mainDiv').trigger('create');
```

But you should be passing the variable `mainDiv`:

```
$(mainDiv).trigger('create');
```

Please see the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/P62Cp/.

Comment: where exactly should I put it? at the end of code (provided)? Because if yes it is stil not working.

Comment: ty, I have udpated my code(whole code) as you can see in edit but it is not working, can you check it please?

Comment: using whole code I have provided I can see text, but still no button.

Comment: @horin: The issue is that you are calling `trigger('create')` before you've inserted the elements into the DOM. You should be able to change the line `mainDiv.appendChild(div);` into `mainDiv.appendChild(div).trigger('create');` or just put `$('mainDiv').trigger('create');` after it.

Comment: ok, I have changed the code (as you can see in edit) and put $('mainDiv').trigger('create'); after it but it still isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = document.createElement("button");
a.innerText = "Submit";
a.id = "addition";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```